# How to debug flutter engine on android with clion

Tags: flutter, debugging, gdb, clion, flutter-engine

I want to debug flutter engine on android by IDEs such as clion or vscode.

Google provides a way to debug the flutter engine on Android(https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master_archived/sky/tools/flutter_gdb#L13). It's base on gdb. Clion provides 'Remote GDB Server'. So maybe there's a way for clion to debug the engine code.